# Directive function not running

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this directive:

```
angular.module('colab.dropdown', []).directive('colabDropdown', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
           ddlist: '=listtoshow',
           model: '=modeltosave',
           displayField: '=listfieldtoshow',
           fieldtoSave: '=listfieldtosave'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {    
        var ddlist = scope.ddlist,
        model = scope.model,
        displayField = scope.displayField,
        fieldtoSave = scope.fieldtoSave,
        rowIdx = scope.rowIndex;

        rowIdx = null;


     for(var i=0;i < ddlist.length;i++){

      if(ddlist[i][attrs.listfieldtosave] == model){
        rowIdx = i;
      }

     }

    if(rowIdx !== null){
      scope.displayField = ddlist[rowIdx][attrs.listfieldtoshow];
    }

    console.log(scope.displayField);

    scope.selectItem = function(unit) {        
          console.log(unit);

    // var idx = scope[attrs.listtoshow].indexOf(unit);        
    // scope[attrs.modeltosave] = unit[attrs.listfieldtosave];
    // scope.listfieldtoshow  = unit[attrs.listfieldtoshow]; 
     };     
    }
    }
});
```

here is my template:

```
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" 
            name="chickenEgg" 
            ng-value="mm.id" 
            ng-model="formData.chickenEgg"
            ng-change="selectItem(mm)"
            >
            {{mm.name}} - {{mm.year}}
        </label>
    </div>
```

I am not able to do the following:

1. run function `selectedItem()` in my template when I click the radio.
2. display the `{{displayField}}` in the DOM.  I can display it in the console (line 38 of the directive) but not in the DOM.  see the plunker console**

> I can run the `selectItem()` if I don't have the `scope:{...}` in the directive.

http://plnkr.co/edit/wuLmJs5f6hVhPEP7OqKS?p=preview

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add you add your **selectItem()** function to **angular-hovercard.js** file.

```
$scope.selectItem = function(item) {
    console.log(item);   
            }
```

[Check it Out](http://plnkr.co/edit/3T4Nj7Og9hcMNqRNNYoS?p=preview)